# How do I add a property to a player object?

Tags: java, bukkit

I don't quite know if those are the correct words, but in my plugin, the players have to choose a class and I don't quite know how to separate the classes. Each class gets unique spells/abilities. If I could add a property (e.g. a boolean for each class; true if they are that class, false otherwise) to a player and return the value, that would solve my problem. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If the property does not need to be maintained across server instances, use the [`Metadatable`](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit-JavaDoc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/metadata/Metadatable.java) interface of `Player`. However, it is difficult (and slow) to use and is not saved on shut down or reload.

You can use a `Map` to map the UUID of each player to the property:

```
private static final Map<UUID, Boolean> playerProperties = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    // Load from file / database
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    // Save to file / database
}
```

From there, you can get the property of a player with `playerProperties.get(player.getUUID())`.

However, since the property is a boolean value, it is more efficient algorithm-wise to use a `Set` and store players with the property, checking the property with [`Set#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
private static final Set<UUID> playerProperties = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    // Load from file / database
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    // Save to file / database
}

public boolean getPlayerProperty(Player player) {
    return playerProperties.contains(player.getUUID());
}

public void setPlayerProperty(Player player, boolean newProperty) {
    if (newProperty)
        playerProperties.add(player.getUUID());
    else
        playerProperties.remove(player.getUUID());
}
```

Comment: I am new to hash maps. Can you store like a string with a boolean value for each player?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this with Metadata. Take a look at https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/ at Package org.bukkit.metadata